# how to return tupplearray from dictionary here is the my Dictionary<String, Array<MyRecords>>() to [(String,Array<MyRecords>)]

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewlayout

how to convert var Dictionary String, ArrayMyCushyRecords() to [(String,Array)]

Comment: add somer relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

Simple generic solution:

```
func dictionaryToTuple<K, V>(dictionary: [K:V]) -> [(K, V)]
{
   return dictionary.map{ ($0.0, $0.1) }
}
```